# App crashes when closing Keyboard on Android Delphi Xe7

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

Create a new project. Drop two TEdits on a form. Deploy to Android device. Start up App. Tap a TEdit to bring up the keyboard, hit the hardware back button on your phone... Crash... Is this something specific to me? or can other people confirm this? Is there something wrong that I am doing? I've tried setting the Key:=0 on the keydown event of the form and the TEdits but that didn't work - app still crashes.

Delphi XE7 update 1 installed.

Comment: Can you get a stack trace of the crash? It's possible to deploy an app to a real device and still run under the debugger, so you should be able to tell exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: Can you post some code, because the problem that you describe I do not have.

OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp (in TEdit) does not work on Android - it works only in Windows.

Comment: I've had the same problem. I solved it by making a new project in a different directory and adding the old project files. I couldn't find the exact problem but it was somewhere in the *.dproj. Hope it helps

Comment: Thought I was going crazy. If you post as answer, I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project and add your classes to it. Problem is somewhere in the .dproj file