# Delphi Android App crash on keyboard connect/disconnect

Tags: android, delphi, keyboard, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

Create an Android App, drop an edit box, run the App.

- Connect a barcode scanner, the App Crash.
- Connect the barcode scanner and run the App, everything works fine.
- Disconnect the scanner and the App crash.

If the App is runnig you cannot connect/disconnect a keyboard/barcode scanner no matter if it is bluetooth or wired.

Any ideas?

Similar to [App crashes when closing Keyboard on Android Delphi Xe7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306329/app-crashes-when-closing-keyboard-on-android-delphi-xe7) 
but it is not the same issue.

LogCat from Running App and then connect the barcode scanner

```
01-28 15:23:26.724 I/ActivityManager(668): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity} from pid 2642
01-28 15:23:26.779 I/ActivityManager(668): Start proc com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication for activity com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity: pid=17902 uid=10178 gids={50178, 3002, 3001, 1006, 3003, 5012, 1028, 1015}
01-28 15:23:28.424 I/ActivityManager(668): Displayed com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity: +1s655ms
01-28 15:23:28.884 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] setSynchronousMode: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:28.884 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] queueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:28.884 W/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:28.889 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:28.889 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:28.889 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:28.889 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:36.054 I/WindowState(668): WIN DEATH: Window{41d09040 u0 com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}
01-28 15:23:36.054 I/ActivityManager(668): Process com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication (pid 17902) has died.
01-28 15:23:36.054 W/ActivityManager(668): Force removing ActivityRecord{41612fe0 u0 com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}: app died, no saved state
01-28 15:23:49.274 I/ActivityManager(668): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity} from pid 2642
01-28 15:23:49.434 I/ActivityManager(668): Start proc com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication for activity com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity: pid=18029 uid=10178 gids={50178, 3002, 3001, 1006, 3003, 5012, 1028, 1015}
01-28 15:23:51.094 I/ActivityManager(668): Displayed com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity: +1s668ms
01-28 15:23:51.589 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] setSynchronousMode: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:51.589 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] queueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:51.589 W/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:51.589 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:51.594 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:51.594 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:51.599 E/BufferQueue(142): [com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
01-28 15:23:59.329 W/InputDispatcher(668): channel '419b5198 com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
01-28 15:23:59.329 E/InputDispatcher(668): channel '419b5198 com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-28 15:23:59.329 W/InputDispatcher(668): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '419b5198 com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity (server)'
01-28 15:23:59.329 I/WindowState(668): WIN DEATH: Window{419b5198 u0 com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}
01-28 15:23:59.334 I/ActivityManager(668): Process com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication (pid 18029) has died.
01-28 15:23:59.334 W/ActivityManager(668): Force removing ActivityRecord{419ef278 u0 com.embarcadero.HeaderFooterApplication/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}: app died, no saved state
```

Comment: Without providing error codes or further details about the crash, there is nothing anyone can do to help you with this.

Comment: THere is not error code, the App just close, that's it. How can I get the error code?

Comment: Assuming you have root access to the device, use `adb logcat` to view the system logs. You should find details of the crash in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution from [Embarcadero Community site](http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/answers/android-connect-disconnect-external-keyboard-make-app-crash#reply-1051) (updated with additional items as suggested by Ernie Thomason)

You need to add `keyboard` into the Android Manifest template `AndroidManifest.template.xml` to avoid app termination when connecting/disconnecting an external USB keyboard.

Current file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Updated file:

```
android:configChanges="orientati‌​on|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|screenSize"
```

Here is some additional information about the template file:

When you build your project, RAD Studio uses `AndroidManifest.template.xml` as a template to generate `AndroidManifest.xml` in the output directory. You will need to edit the template file which lives in the same folder as your project.

Comment: Thanks Dalija, I'm the same person who posted in Embarcadero Community Site. I asked Sarina D to answer it here too to give her the credit.

Comment: I haven't seen Sarina D, answering questions here, so I posted answer with link to her answer to provide solution for others facing same issue that will search for answers on SO.

Comment: I had to add a few more items so that my activity would not get restarted on keyboard connect.  My full list: android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|orientation|screenSize"

Comment: @ErnieThomason Thank you, I have updated answer to make it more complete.